# MonadException instance is not deduced

Tags: haskell

Maybe I'm doing something stupid here, but I'm getting:

```
No instance for (MonadException Ti)
  arising from a use of `getInputLine'
```

in the code sample:

```
module Foo where
import System.Console.Haskeline
import System.Console.Haskeline.MonadException
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

type Ti = StateT Int IO

action :: String -> Ti ()
action s = do
    n <- get
    lift $ putStrLn $ show n ++ ": " ++ s

repl :: InputT Ti ()
repl = do
    minput <- getInputLine "?"
    case minput of
        Nothing    -> return ()
        Just input -> lift (action input) >> repl
```

Now, `System.Console.Haskeline.MonadException` defines

```
MonadException IO
(MonadIO (StateT s m), MonadException m) => MonadException (StateT s m)
```

and `Control.Monad.IO.Class`:

```
MonadIO IO
MonadIO m => MonadIO (StateT s m)
```

So, shouldn't it deduce the instance for `Ti` automatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no instance for the Lazy state transformer, just the strict one. Use `import Control.Monad.State.Strict`.